# Update page does not update properties

Tags: notion-api

When making the call according to the following documentation https://developers.notion.com/reference/patch-page, it does not update the properties despite returning code 200

try the following curl:
`curl --location --request PATCH 'http://api.notion.com/v1/pages/0da8e22e-855e-42e7-85cf-5cd67ff9a603' \ --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXX' \ --header 'Notion-Version: 2022-06-28' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --header 'Cookie: __cf_bm=c.RL4q7VAk__b6eGsN0tHdquBKICnyTPddJL1i5wXz4-1674348742-0-Acii2wBNQqYV3u0HXiVh9G0jxW4lA4XbdnwMSbn5h+rVIrPNgYik9CwqUcW+HrlI6XkIZ7vwpTngBtWIzjdez/g=' \ --data-raw '{   "properties": {     "Vendidos": { "number": 5}  } }'`

The notion table is:
[table notion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTJ0B.png)

Try for name properties and ID

Always returns 200OK without updating the property

I tried with other properties too and not work update page endpoint

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? looks like I am facing the same issue and can't find any info on why it does not update